# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Error binding parameter 1: type 'list' is not supported ошибка при работе с базами данных

Tags: python, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(text=['✅ Начать'])
async def regi(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(' Вы успешно зарегистрировались! Всю свою информацию теперь вы можете посмотреть в профиле.', reply_markup=mainkb)

    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    user_id = [message.chat.id]
    username = [message.from_user.username]
    datereg = [message.date]

    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES(?,?,?);", (user_id, username, datereg))

    conn.commit()
```

хотел чтобы когда пользователь нажимал на кнопку начать, вводились данные в базу, вместо этого выдаёт ошибку которая в заголовке

Comment: `[чего-нибудь]` — это создание списка. зачем же вы их создаёте?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте передать данные в явном виде

```
user_id = message.chat.id
username = message.from_user.username
datereg = message.date
```